# Refreshing a component in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am designing a dashboard based on `angular 6`. My dashboard has several different components arranged together. I want to refresh a component after every 5 minutes.

I have tried `windows.location.reload()` and `location.reload()` however it is refreshing the entire page and not just one component , i.e. to be specefic all my components are getting refreshed. So, please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: This component that you want to refresh, what exactly are you looking to refresh? Is there some data or some chart etc that you want to update?

Comment: You could use the @ViewChildren decorator to get a handle on the components in the page, then individually call ngOnInit() in them. Not tried it personally. Why do you need to refresh them though, if it's a matter of updating data shouldn't it be doing that seamlessly anyway?

Comment: You do not reload SPA, you call API, get fresh data and update them in component.

Comment: You need to refresh the Data by updating the latest values from API to the Component properties with setTimeout/setInterval. Don't reload the page as single Page application is good updating the component based on router access

Comment: The data through the API is changing after some time.....so i need to make http requests every 10 minutes to detect and reflect those changes in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

> Try this out

```js
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {    
setInterval(() => {
  this.ref.detectChanges();
 }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I searched through so many pages here and this is finally an answer that is working, especially when you are trying to update a component from another component by using subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'; // Angular 6 
// import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'; // Angular 5

  Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
    this.router.navigate(["Your actualComponent"]));
  });
```

OR

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'; // Angular 6 
// import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'; // Angular 5

  Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
    this.ngOnInit();
  });
```

Comment: This isn't working for me....it's saying that interval does not exist for type observable

Comment: what is your rxjs version ?

Comment: I solved the problem using set interval method.....it worked...Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => { this.ngOnInit() }, 1000 * 10)
  //Interval = 10secs
}
```